# Reading files after giving path from stdin

Tags: node.js

How can I read file after defining the path through standard input? I get an error that path is not the string.

```
const path = process.stdin;
const lines = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf-8").split("\n").filter(Boolean);
let numberOfElephants = lines[0];
let massOfElephants = lines[1].split(" ").map((mass) => +mass);

let elephantsOrderGiven = lines[2].split(" ").map((order) => +order);

let proposedOrder = lines[3].split(" ").map((order) => +order);
```

Comment: `process.stdin` is a stream, you have to read the stream and handle the given data. `process.stdi` is not a string.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html should be the api you're looking for